# Having trouble serving image from django rest API using angular

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

I am currently having an issue rendering an image from my newly created products API using Django REST Framework. I have everything else loading but the images will not load.

I am using angular to consume the API data with the following code:

```
    myStore.controller("myStoreController",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.gems = $http.get("/api/products/").then(
            function(response){
                $scope.gems = response.data
            }, function(error){
                $scope.error = error
            });


})
```

Here is the product rest URL code:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url,include
from rest_framework import routers
from products_rest.viewsets import ProductsViewsets

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('products',ProductsViewsets,'products')

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)) #base router
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Lastly, here is the main settings URL for the django app:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('customerreview_rest.urls', namespace='api')),
    url(r'^api/',include ('products_rest.urls', namespace='api')),
    url(r'^', include('GemStore_App.urls',namespace='frontend')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I navigate to the URL of the image, I can access the image, but for whatever reason I can't get the image to display to the page.

[image]

And the API looks like this currently:

```
[
{
    "name": "Dodecahedron",
    "price": 30,
    "description": "Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their lustre, beyond their shine. This is one of them",
    "images": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/gem-01.gif",
    "canPurchase": true
},
```

**EDIT ** Here is the HTML for the project:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myStore">
<head>
    <title>Gem Store App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/reviews.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/myStoreController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/myPanelController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/myReviewsController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div ng-controller="myStoreController" class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="product in gems" class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>{{product.name }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div>
                <img ng-repeat="image in product.images track by $index" ng-src='{{image.full}}'/>
            </div>
                <h2 >{{product.price | currency}}</h2>
                <button ng-show="product.canPurchase" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
            <section ng-init="tab = 1" ng-controller="myPanelController">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li ng-class="{ active:isSelected(1) }"><a ng-click="selectTab(1)">Description</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active:isSelected(2) }"><a ng-click="selectTab(2)">Specifications</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isSelected(3) }"><a ng-click="selectTab(3)">Reviews</a></li>
                </ul>


                <div class="panel" ng-show = "isSelected(1)">
                    <h4>Description</h4>
                    <blockquote>{{product.description}}</blockquote>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" ng-show = "isSelected(2)">
                    <h4>Specifications</h4>
                    <blockquote>Nothing yet</blockquote>
                </div>
                <div ng-app="storeReviews">
                    <div class="panel" ng-show="isSelected(3)" reviews ng-controller="myReviewsController"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how are you binding the image on Angular?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the index.html...I am binding to it using a repeater in angular. Please see my update for more details.

Comment: `product.images` is a string and how could you ng-repeat it? don't you have any console logs?

Comment: do you have a list of images or just an image at `product.images`? Your API shows just one.

Comment: I don't have any console logged errors in that regard...wouldn't the URL string be evaluated and serve up the image? That was what I was initially thinking

Comment: I have a list of different products...only one image per product though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your `<img>` tag to

```
<img ng-src='{{product.images}}'/>
```

would make it work. If you wanted was a list of images, then restructure your API accordingly.

Comment: Thank you sir! I got so stuck on the api that I didn't even rethink about my html completely. I appreciate your efforts good sir!